# C# - How to Search and Filter in DataGridView without BindingSource

Tags: c#, search, datagridview, filter, sqlite

I wanna make a Search on **Data Grid View** in **C#** and **SQLite**, but I don't have **Binding Source** for Datagridview. I fill Datagridview with following code:

```
SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=gasstation.sqlite;Version=3");

dt = new DataTable();
SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT ID,fname, lname, nationalCode," + 
      personalCode, phone ,address, datetime(dateEnter) as dateEnter FROM Workers", conn);
conn.Open();
SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);

da.Fill(dt);               

SQLiteDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
DateTime date;
PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();                
while (read.Read())
{
    date = read.GetDateTime(7);
    string datePC = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", pc.GetYear(date), 
                                  pc.GetMonth(date), pc.GetDayOfMonth(date));

    dgvUsers.Rows.Add(new object[] { 
        read.GetValue(0),
        read.GetValue(1),
        read.GetValue(2),
        read.GetValue(3),
        read.GetValue(4),
        read.GetValue(5),
        read.GetValue(6),
        datePC   });
    }
    read.Close();
    conn.Close();
}
```

How to make a Search and filtering on Data Grid View with Text change event of Text Box.

**I saw all of Question and Answer in StackOverflow but it doesn't right answer to my problem.**

Comment: Why don' you create a BindingSource?

Comment: @TaW : I don't no how to create BindingSource on this code.

Comment: See my answer; you need to use an object that implements IBindingList. Since you already have the DataTable it is the natural  choice. See my answer on how to do that and how to supplement the table with the computed column!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a little confused.

**First** you fill all the data into a `DataTable` with a `DataAdapter`, which looks fine. But **then** you read them **once more** in a `DataReader` and fill them into the `DataGridView` in code.

This is not necessary. Forget the reader and the loop it is in!

If the `DataTable` contains the data you can bind the `DGV` to that table:

```
dgvUsers.DataSource = dt;
```

When binding directly you can't sort or filter, though. Therefore it is better to create a `BindingSource` and make it the DGV's `DataSource`:

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource(dt, "");
```

Note the second parameter: It is empty, since we are using a single table as the data source of the `BindingSource`. Had we used a `DataSet` we would have put the `TableName` there. You don't have set the `TableName` property; it is better to do so, so let's change the instantiation to `dt = new DataTable("someTableName");`

Now we can bind the `DGV` to the data via the `BindingSource`:

```
dgvUsers.DataSource = bs;
```

Finally we can set the `Sort` and `Filter` properties as needed.

From some other control we can cast back to `BindingSource`, maybe like this:

```
private void textBox_lastName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindingSource bs = dgvUsers.DataSource as BindingSource;

    if (textBox_lastName.Text == "") bs.RemoveFilter(); 
    else bs.Filter =  "lname like '%" +  textBox_lastName.Text + "%'";
}
```

I note that in the loop you are creating a formatted date field. I suspect that it is the reason for creating that loop in the first place..? But you can add it to the `DataTable` just as well; the best way, of course is, as always, to select the value you want and let the DBMS do all the work.

But if you want to do very special stuff you don't trust the SQL function to achieve, like using that `PersianCalendar` class, you can add a **dummy** field to your `SELECT`:

```
   SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT ID,fname, lname ,nationalCode, " + 
      "personalCode, phone, address, datetime(dateEnter) as dateEnter " + 
      "\"\" as pcDate FROM Workers", conn);
```

..and after filling the table fill that dummy field with the special values:

```
DateTime date;
PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();

foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
   date = row.Field<DateTime>("dateEnter");
   string datePC = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", 
                   pc.GetYear(date), pc.GetMonth(date), pc.GetDayOfMonth(date));
   row.SetField<string>("pcDate", datePC);
}
```

Of couse you may now want to hide the `dateEnter` column from the DVG:

```
dgvUsers.Columns["dateEnter"].Visible = false;
```

Comment: Thank you. This is best answer.

Comment: In SQLiteCommand,  `SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT ID,fname, lname ,nationalCode, " + 
      "personalCode, phone, address, datetime(dateEnter) as dateEnter " + 
      "\"\" as pcDate FROM Workers", conn);` has Error:

`database schema has changed. near """: syntax error.`

Comment: I solved prev error, I set `SQLiteCommand`: `SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT ID,fname,lname,nationalCode,phone,address,datetime(dateEnter) as dateEnter,'persianDate' AS pcDate FROM Workers", conn);`

Comment: I don't know why  `date = row.Field<DateTime>("dateEnter");` has `Specified cast is not valid` error. But I think it is TRUE. @TaW

Comment: Hm, the sql looks good. You can test if the field contains a valid date in the debugger or does the error come from the compiler??

Comment: Yes,it has valid date. It showed date in DGV, but I don't know why can't casting. @TaW

Comment: Seeing it in the DGV is not a certain way to assure the type of a field. Do put a breakpoint at the line `date = row.Field<DateTime>("dateEnter");` and look into `row`. strings and numbers are displayed directly, but a Date field will have a little plus and you can expand it to look at the datetime parts.. Do you get the plus for this filed??

Comment: Hm, Yes, it has. But type is `string`. I think it cause error and it will be `DateTime`. Right? @TaW

Comment: Hm strange; for strings I don't get the plus. There is also a reference to the Table and its columns. You can check the types of the columns/fields there as well. Yes, if it is string the cast will fail. Your SQL clearly has `Select ..datetime(dateEnter‌​)` but maybe you really should only select the `dataEnter` field without the datetime function?? [sqlite datetime](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) creates datetime from datestrings. Still I would expect the columns created to be datetimes..

Comment: I solved it, `string stringdate = row.Field<string>("dateEnter");
                    date = Convert.ToDateTime(stringdate);  ` @TaW

Comment: Godd for you, sometimes getting it to work is what counts and not understanding it all.. ;-)